# How to call a function containing If/Else using User Input in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, function, if-statement, user-input, alert

How do I go about nesting an If/Else statement into a function and then calling that function using a user input in the body in order to make the function calculate the correct alert with JavaScript? I'm missing the knowledge of how to call the statement in the body it seems. Any help would be appreciated! :)

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <title> JavaScript Playground </title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function grade(Grade){
            if (Grade <= 90 && Grade >= 100) {
                return alert("You made an A!");
            } else {
                return alert("I don't know what you made!");
            }
        }
    </script>   
</head>
    <body>
        <script>
        var Grade = parseFloat(prompt("Please enter a number: "));</script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Just put the line `grade(Grade);` after the `var Grade = ...` line? You call a function by writing its name follwed by putting `(...)`. Between the parenthesis go the arguments. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Functions#Calling_functions

Comment: Wow thanks man! I feel like an idiot. I appreciate the help and the link to the guide you sent me! I'm a new student to software development and I didn't know that there was an entire document for learning JavaScript. 

I appreciate it so much!

Comment: There are a couple of great resources for learning JavaScript out there: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide, https://eloquentjavascript.net/, https://exploringjs.com/impatient-js/index.html

Answer (score 2):

Several things

1. Your value cannot be <=90 AND >= 100
2. No need to return the alert
3. You need to call the prompt before the grade or move the prompt to the function
4. Prompt can return empty string, or something not a number so test if it is a number

Your code could be written

```
function grade(){
  var Grade = prompt("Please enter a number: "); 
  Grade = isNaN(Grade) || Grade.trim()==="" ? 0 : +Grade; // force number if "Not a Number" or an empty string
  if (Grade >= 90 && Grade <= 100) {
    alert("You made an A!");
  } else {
     alert("I don't know what you made!");
  }
}
grade()
```

That said,

5. You should already use eventListeners
6. It is nicer to use some element's text content than an alert
7. I also show you a [ternary](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) instead of the `if (a) text = "a"; else if (b) text = "b"` construct

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <title> JavaScript Playground </title>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    // helper function to make a number from whatever is entered
    const makeNum = str => isNaN(str) || str.trim() === "" ? 0 : +str; // convert to 0 if not a number
    
    function grade(Grade) {
      Grade = makeNum(Grade); // convert to number
      return Grade >= 90 && Grade <= 100 ? "You made an A!" : "I don't know what you made!";
    }
    window.addEventListener("load",function() { // on page load
      document.getElementById("gradeMe").addEventListener("click",function() {
        document.getElementById("res").textContent = grade(document.getElementById('grade').value);
      })
    });
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  Please enter a number:
  <input type="text" id="grade">
  <input type="button" id="gradeMe" value="grade me" />
  <span id="res"></span>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You could also add the prompt() returns one of three things: (1) a string, (2) an empty string if the user enters nothing and just clicks OK or (3) null, if the user clicks Cancel.  Any string returned may or may not be a number.  Thus, the code will need to check for non-numeric responses, empty strings or nulls as well.

Comment: We haven't learned event listeners or even went over them in the class as of yet. We are doing 2 pages, one for if/else and one for Switch Statements. I need to look up event listeners and see how they are used. I appreciate the feed back! I'll go search them up now! :) Also, I love the way you rewrote it, it looks much smoother and runs better also!

Comment: @MrPerserva I just wanted to give you some better codes. The first example I gave is ok for now - I did add some input validation for you

Answer (score 0):

The line directly after

```
var Grade = parseFloat(prompt("Please enter a number: "));
```

You can call your function like `grade(Grade);`

The if/else is completely unrelated to how you call the function but I think the conditional inside your if statement is mixed up. I'm guessing you probably meant for it to be `Grade >= 90 && Grade <= 100` rather than `Grade <= 90 && Grade >= 100`.

Comment: Yeah! The <= was a mishap and completely accidental.
I appreciate the step-by-step on how to think of the if/else as unrelated to the call. 

I really appreciate the help!